# Formatting axis value in tooltip for trigger=item

Tags: echarts

I have a line chart with months plotted on the x axis and the values for each month on the y axis.
It looks like this

[image]

my option config is

```
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Title',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    axisPointer: {
      label: {
        formatter: 'format1',
      },
    },
  },
  legend: {},
  xAxis: {
    axisPointer: {
      label: {
        formatter: 'format2',
      },
    },
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: 'format3',
    },
    type: 'category',
    splitLine: {
      show: true,
    },
    axisLine: {
      show: true,
    },
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      position: 'right',
      type: 'value',
      splitLine: {
        show: true,
      },
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  dataset: {
    source: [
      {
        month: 1420070400000,
        value1: 5,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1422748800000,
        value1: 10,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1425168000000,
        value1: 11,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1427846400000,
        value1: 15,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1430438400000,
        value1: 20,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1433116800000,
        value1: 5,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1435708800000,
        value1: 10,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1438387200000,
        value1: 15,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1441065600000,
        value1: 20,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1443657600000,
        value1: 0,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1446336000000,
        value1: 10,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1448928000000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1451606400000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1454284800000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1456790400000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1459468800000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1462060800000,
        value1: 12,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1464739200000,
        value1: 22,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1467331200000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1470009600000,
        value1: 12,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1472688000000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1475280000000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1477958400000,
        value1: 22,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
      {
        month: 1480550400000,
        value1: 2,
        value2: 1,
        value3: 3,
        value4: 4,
      },
    ],
    dimensions: ['month', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'],
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        formatter: 'format4',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        formatter: 'format4',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        formatter: 'format4',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        formatter: 'format4',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I am using `trigger: 'item'` for tooltip for which my tooltip looks like in the screen shot.
I need to format the month value in the tooltip to `MMM-YYYY` format for which I would use a formatter function like

```
function formatter(params) {
  console.log(params);
  return dayjs(params.value.month).format('MMM, YYYY');
}
```

if I specify the formatter in `series[index].tooltip.formatter`, it replaces the entire tooltip with the value returned by the formatter and not just the month value.

How do I just format the month value in the tooltip keeping the other contents of the tooltip as they are by default?

link for live demo: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple

Answer (score 0):

Echart allows you to modify all fields in tooltip not just one field. So you need to build all remaining fields while using tooltip formatter. All required details will be present in params. You can use below formatter

```
function formatter(params) {
   console.log(params);
   return `${params.seriesName}<br>${params.marker} ${dayjs(params.value.month).format('MMM, YYYY')`enter code here`}: ${params.value[params.seriesName]}`;
}
```